# iOS View Controller Life Cycle when Performing Segue Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

Bascially, I want to push a new VC from the current navigation controller of the current VC. While pushing to the new VC, I want to set the value to the new VC. For example:

Old VC Push Part:

```
GFRepositoryViewController *reposVC = [[GFRepositoryViewController alloc]init];
            reposVC.userName = self.userNameTextField.text;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:reposVC animated:YES];
```

New VC .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *userName;
```

Basically, there is no problem while getting the value of "userName" in the new VC. However, I have questions about the life cycle of the VC.

Since the new VC "GFRepositoryViewController" is allocated in the old VC, therefore, there should be a strong pointer pointing from the old VC to the new VC. And once push to the new VC, the old VC should be deallocated. Therefore, the new VC should also be deallocated, since there is a strong pointer to it. And therefore, the value "userName" should also be deallocated. However, I can get the value in the new VC successfully. That is why I am curious about it.

Comment: It is not deallocated. It still exists in the navigation stack.Once you dismiss the view controller then it will be deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

None of these controllers is being deallocated, because both of them are embeded in `UINavigationController` object. When using `UINavigationController`'s  methods

- `initWithRootViewController`
- `pushViewController:animated`

the new controller is being added to the navigationController's `viewControllers` property which is an `NSArray` object. It only holds strong references.